# AdMob Ads stops working from time to time in the Release App

Tags: android, admob

My app is published on play store and ads were working fine but suddenly yesterday it stopped showing ads in all device.

I uninstalled the app and installed back then my ads starting working again but today it stopped working again.

I not received any mail from AdMob and account is working fine.

I don't know what's happening with my app. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out the reason for this behavior,
Sometimes ads are not available in inventory and that's why they are not displayed in the app.
Now using AdMob mediation I am using the app of different providers and not encountered this problem.

Answer (score 1):

try these rules in proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class com.google.unity.** {*;}

-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {*;}

-keep class com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter {*;}

-keep class com.google.ads.mediation.AdUrlAdapter {*;}
```

Comment: I use Firebase Ads, Should I have to use same code or is there different for Firebase ads